# Using GaussianProcessHyperparameterOpt in Deepchem

Tags: python, keyerror

I am trying to use the `hyperparam_search` function in GaussianProcessHyperparamOpt, in Deepchem. I'm following what's done in the testscript for the HyperparamOpt class (there is no test for the gaussianprocess class):

After loading the training set etc, I'm defining a dicitonary for the hyperparamters:

```
hps = {
      'layer_sizes': [1500],
      'weight_init_stddevs': [0.02],
      'bias_init_consts': [1.],
      'dropouts': [0.5],
      'penalty': 0.1,
      'penalty_type': 'l2',
      'batch_size': 50,
      'nb_epoch': 10,
      'learning_rate': 0.001  }
```

Then I'm making a model_builder function (this I copied/pasted from the test script):

```
def model_builder(model_params, model_dir):
       return dc.models.MultitaskRegressor(
           len(tasks), n_features, model_dir=model_dir, **model_params)
```

Then I'm defining the metric, which is according to the code is supposed to be given as a list of length 1:

```
regression_metric = [dc.metrics.Metric(dc.metrics.r2_score)]
```

Then I'm calling the `hyperparameter_search` function, giving the four required arguments:

```
optimizer = dc.hyper.GaussianProcessHyperparamOpt(model_builder)
best_hyper_params, best_performance, all_results = optimizer.hyperparam_search(
    hps, 
    train,
    valid,
    transformers,
    regression_metric
)
```

And I get a KeyValue error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-85-be984f768f5b> in <module>()
      5     valid,
      6     transformers,
----> 7     metric = regression_metric
      8 )
      9 #    metric = regression_metric

1 frames

/usr/lib/python3.6/os.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    667         except KeyError:
    668             # raise KeyError with the original key value
--> 669             raise KeyError(key) from None
    670         return self.decodevalue(value)
    671 

KeyError: 'DEEPCHEM_DATA_DIR'
```

To prove, I'm not crazy, here is the code for the function, you can see it expects a metric as 4th argument

```
 23   def hyperparam_search(
 24       self,
 25       params_dict,
 26       train_dataset,
 27       valid_dataset,
 28       output_transformers,
 29       metric,
 30       direction=True,
 31       n_features=1024,
 32       n_tasks=1,
 33       max_iter=20,
 34       search_range=4,
 35       hp_invalid_list=[
 36           'seed', 'nb_epoch', 'penalty_type', 'dropouts', 'bypass_dropouts',
 37           'n_pair_feat', 'fit_transformers', 'min_child_weight',
 38           'max_delta_step', 'subsample', 'colsample_bylevel',
 39           'colsample_bytree', 'reg_alpha', 'reg_lambda', 'scale_pos_weight',
 40           'base_score'
 41       ],
 42       log_file='GPhypersearch.log'):
 43     """Perform hyperparams search using a gaussian process assumption
 44 
 45     params_dict include single-valued parameters being optimized,
 46     which should only contain int, float and list of int(float)
 47 
 48     parameters with names in hp_invalid_list will not be changed.
 49 
 50     For Molnet models, self.model_class is model name in string,
 51     params_dict = dc.molnet.preset_hyper_parameters.hps[self.model_class]
 52 
 53     Parameters
 54     ----------
 55     params_dict: dict
 56       dict including parameters and their initial values
 57       parameters not suitable for optimization can be added to hp_invalid_list
 58     train_dataset: dc.data.Dataset struct
 59       dataset used for training
 60     valid_dataset: dc.data.Dataset struct
 61       dataset used for validation(optimization on valid scores)
 62     output_transformers: list of dc.trans.Transformer
 63       transformers for evaluation
 64     metric: list of dc.metrics.Metric
 65       metric used for evaluation
```

Here's were it gets funky: If I pass the metric as an object, and not as a list containing an object:

```
regression_metric = dc.metrics.Metric(dc.metrics.r2_score)
```

I don't get a KeyValue error, but then it crashes when the function checks that the metric is a list of length 1:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-87-be984f768f5b> in <module>()
      5     valid,
      6     transformers,
----> 7     metric = regression_metric
      8 )
      9 #    metric = regression_metric

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/deepchem/hyper/gaussian_process.py in hyperparam_search(self, params_dict, train_dataset, valid_dataset, output_transformers, metric, direction, n_features, n_tasks, max_iter, search_range, hp_invalid_list, log_file)
     89     """
     90 
---> 91     assert len(metric) == 1, 'Only use one metric'
     92     hyper_parameters = params_dict
     93     hp_list = list(hyper_parameters.keys())

TypeError: object of type 'Metric' has no len()
```

Any Deepchem users out there, if you've made this function work, please chime in!

Answer (score 0):

We did some back and forth debugging in the gitter channel, and it turned out there were a few underlying bugs that were causing this issue. Here are couple of the issues documenting the fixes:

- https://github.com/deepchem/deepchem/issues/1821
- https://github.com/deepchem/deepchem/issues/1814

Thanks for your help surfacing these issues! The next stable version of DeepChem should have these issues fixed.